# How to customise DialogTitle in material-ui

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am learning react and material-ui and trying to update the colour of the font in the DialogTitle component. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51820154/how-to-i-change-font-color-in-dialogtitle-and-dialogcontent-in-material-ui-in-re) gave a solution of overriding the dialog root class (code listed below). How do I override the root class for DialogTitle so that I can change the style of the title?

```js
root: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.main,
    '& h6': {
      color: 'red'
    }
  }
```

Found a [solution](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/9072).

```js
<DialogTitle
    disableTypography
    id="alert-dialog-title"
    style={{ backgroundColor: 'navy', color: 'white' }}
>
    <Typography variant="h6">{ErrorBoundary.title}</Typography>
</DialogTitle>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to override the DialogTitle in your `theme.js` file, or wherever your theme is located, you can do the following:

```
MuiDialogTitle: {
  root: {
    color: 'blue'
  }
}
```

You have to mention the component class name. In the API section of every material ui component, the [name is specified here](https://material-ui.com/api/dialog-title/#css):

[image]

Comment: Thanks @kag359six. Have applied a solution from https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/9072. Will accept your the answer.